# Laravel pass array from Helper function and return the array to the Controller

Tags: php, laravel, function, controller, helper

Hey may I know why my code is wrong. I'm trying to copy a value from Helpers function to Controllers. Here is my code in the Helper Functions.

```
function checkMenu(){

$menu = [
            1 => 'Cake',
            .
            .
            .
            20 => 'Butter',
];

return $menu;
}
```

Here is the coding in my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
.
.
.
.

class MenuController extends Controller
{
 
    $menu = checkMenu();
    
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I got an error which is

```
syntax error, unexpected '$menu' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)
```

And when I write it in this way

```
const $menu = checkMenu();
```

I got an error

```
syntax error, unexpected '$menu' (T_VARIABLE)
```

Comment: Why do YOU think this code is wrong? Are you getting an error??

Comment: As `$menu` does not actually exists before you call this `$menu = checkMenu($menu);` I would assume an error from that

Comment: `$array = $menu;` does nothing useful. You didn't make the parameter passable by reference so its really just noise

Comment: You pass `$menu` as if it is already defined. Try `$menu = checkMenu();` and change the `checkMenu` function to `function checkMenu() {}`. Also, this is a really bad question, if we can even call it a question. There is no context supplied (what does it do that it shouldn't or the other way around). So read how to ask a question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I tried removing the parameter and called it in this way public $menu = checkMenu(); got an error Constant expression contains invalid operations

Comment: @geertjanknapen I've already change the question. Do you know why I am receiving that errors

Comment: You might want to put the whole `$menu = checkMenu();` within a function, for example `public function index() {}` or define it as a private just underneath the class `private $menu = checkMenu();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution by doing something like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
.
.
.
.
class MenuController extends Controller
{
 
    private $menu = []; 
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->menu = checkMenu(); 
    }
.
.
.
}
```